# SSRS Drill through Report not populating parameters automatically

Tags: reporting-services, drillthrough

I've two reports main and drill through, which I’m trying to get to run via the URL. The report will open in a new tab from the URL, but it doesn't run (with the parameters), the user has to select the parameters and one variable is populated from a a common field on both reports. Both reports use the same parameters and both have the same internal parameter. I have this working with 2 other reports that do not contain an internal parameter but this one will not render correctly. I cannot figure out whats wrong.

This is the code in my Go to URL action:

"javascript:void(window.open('https://myserver/Reportserver?/myfolder/Drill_BoEUGTranscripts_ANON&rs:Command=Render&Acad_Period="+Parameters!Acad_Period.Value+"&Aos_Code="& Parameters!Aos_Code.Value+"&Aos_Period="+Parameters!Aos_Period.Value+"&Stage_code="+Parameters!Stage_code.Value+"&anon="+Fields!anon.Value &"','_blank'))"

This is the URL:

https://myserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?/myfolder/Drill_BoEUGTranscripts_ANON&rs:Command=Render&Acad_Period=17/18&Aos_Code=BMUS&Aos_Period=FT3&Stage_code=%25&anon=15015071

but then the drillthorugh is displayed like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLEj0.png)

Comment: have you checked to see that the parameter names are correct.. I mean the case sensitivity and data type? If you set default values of the above on the sub report.. does it run ok?

Comment: Have you tried using the GO TO REPORT option with the exact same parameters to test, whether or no the other report runs? If you are successful in running the drillthrough report this way, you should be able to refine your existing parameters in your URL to make the drillthrough populate.